# Append Fields to node form by ajax call

Tags: 6, forms, ajax

I have a node form with some fields, now I want to append some more fields to it on an ajax callback. in the ajax page I have rendered the new form elements with `drupal_render` function
My problem is that I am not getting the newly built form fields in POST or form_state. 
Shall I use `AHAH` or can I continue with this ajax calls?

```
$form['country'] = array( 
            "#type"=>"select",   
            '#title'    =>t('Ship To'), 
            '#required' => true ,
            '#options' => $options,
            '#weight' =>10,
            '#attributes' =>  array('id' => $cn_var),
        );
        $form['dyn_cost'] = array( 
            "#type"=>"textfield",   
            '#title'    =>t('Shipping Cost'),   
            '#required' => true ,
            '#size' =>25,
            '#weight' =>11,
            '#id' =>  $co_var,
        );

        print drupal_render($form);
        exit;
```

This is my ajax form and it is supposed to be appending to the node form.

Comment: May be you want to check the AJAX examples in the example module.

Comment: Is there any problem with my current code ?

Comment: Use AHAH. By printing and exiting you're not altering the $form that Drupal knows, and it won't accept data that it's not expecting. In D6 it's not as fun as #ajax in D7, though. Check out an answer I just gave that's very similar, although its syntax applies to D7: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/59224/why-does-form-stateinput-not-correspond-to-the-html-of-the-form-upon-submit/59248#59248

Comment: @CharlieS why not to post it as an answer? 
NikhilM are you still interested in this at all?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Conditional Fields](https://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module to display form fields with certain conditions. No need to use custom ajax calls.

> Conditional Fields allows you to manage sets of dependencies between fields. When a field is “dependent”, it will only be available for editing and displayed if the state of the “dependee” field matches the right condition.